# No X11 Display Variable was set ,but this program performed an operation which requires it

Tags: java, x11, display, headless, x11-forwarding

I am trying to run a Java application on Linux boxes but I am getting
this exception: in java.awt.headless exception stating this

> No x11 display variable was set

Also, this code works fine in my locally (windows) but gives exceptions on the Linux server after deployment.
I have tried several ways to do it on Linux as well as on Java side to resolve but still no luck like

```
Setting java.awt.headless =true
```

or false then setting system.property with this then setting display variable with export display and also starting xeyes ,xorg and startx command also tried but still no luck

Please suggest to me how to resolve this exception

This app is generating some images using Jfreechart and for viewing the images we need a display that is not available on Linux but it's on Windows I need to deploy this app anyhow into Linux to make it to production and it's failing at the dev level now.
Please help me resolve this exception. How can I have the Display available in Linux or how can I suppress this I don't need to view the images you just generate the images there itself.

> X11forwarding is also set to yes

Comment: If you can't run xeyes on it then X is probably not installed at all. I would *guess* that you do need X to use JFreeChart *even if nothing needs to be visible*, though why would you want anything visual on a *server*?

Comment: Actually this application is looking for visibility and hence the ask is

Comment: Then you need to install X on the server